# How to extract part of character data to new column

Tags: r, function, grepl

I got this df

```
AGE_TXT
3 weeks
1 year
3 years
```

i use

```
strsplit(df$AGE_TXT, " ")
```

To split data, but i have a problem how to make new column with data

I tryied to use
`grep("year", df$AGE_TXT)`, but it only give me True/False

I wolud like to make new column with data

```
0
1
3
```

0 for 3 weeks, and 1 for 1 year, 3 for 3 years

Comment: so you want three columns?

Comment: I want new column only represennting number years (1 month = 0, 1 year = 1) to be able to compare data ~age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`

```
df$new <- ifelse(grepl('year', df$AGE_TXT), gsub('\\D', '', df$AGE_TXT), 0)
df
#  AGE_TXT new
#1 3 weeks  0
#2  1 year  1
#3 3 years  3
```